# modify the scale of x-axis and y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi every one I would like to modify the scale of x axis and y axis like this picture.
[image]

I'm starting from that code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines,black] (0,0) grid (9,9);
\draw [ultra thick,black, ->] (0,0)--(9.5,0) node[below right] {\textbf{\Huge $X\left[ km \right]$}};
\draw [ultra thick,black, ->] (0,0)--(0,9.5) node[above left] {\textbf{\Huge $Y \left[ km \right]$}};
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
    \draw (\i,.3)--++(-90:6mm) node[below]{\Huge \textbf{\i}};
\foreach \i in {1,...,9}
    \draw (.3,\i)--++(180:6mm) node[left]{\Huge \textbf{\i}};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {\Huge \textbf{0}};

\draw [fill=black] (0.0,0.0) circle (4.0pt);

\draw [ultra thick,black] (0.0,0.0)--(5.0,5.0) node[above left] {\textbf{\Large }};
\draw [fill=black] (5.0,5.0) circle (4.0pt);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pgfplots`? That makes such things much easier.

Comment: Take the code from the answer I posted to one of your other questions yesterday, set `ymax=25,xmax=1,ytick={4,8,...,24},xtick={0.1,0.2,...,1}`

Answer (score 3):

While going for `pgfplots` might be the better option just changing the axis labels is relatively easy:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

    \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2}

    \draw[help lines,black] (0,0) grid (9,9);
    \draw [ultra thick,black, ->] (0,0)--(9.5,0) node[below right] {\textbf{\Huge $X$ \lbrack km\rbrack}};
    \draw [ultra thick,black, ->] (0,0)--(0,9.5) node[above left] {\textbf{\Huge $Y$ \lbrack km\rbrack}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,9}
        \draw (\i,.3)--++(-90:6mm) node[below]{\Large\pgfmathparse{\i/10}$\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
        \draw (.3,\i)--++(180:6mm) node[left]{\Large\pgfmathparse{\i/6*24}$\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$};
    \node[below left] at (0,0) {\Large \textbf{0}};

    \draw [fill=black] (0.0,0.0) circle (4.0pt);

    \draw [ultra thick,black] (0.0,0.0)--(5.0,5.0) node[above left] {\textbf{\Large }};
    \draw [fill=black] (5.0,5.0) circle (4.0pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: (+1) Note the change on the y-axis as well. And if you're editing, I'd suggest `$X$ [km]` for the axis label -- the unit shouldn't be italic.